# Thai restaurant serves a sweet red pepper condiment - what is it called?

Tags: thai-cuisine

A Thai restaurant in Los Angeles I frequent serves red peppers on many of their dishes. They are mild to medium spicy, very sweet, and likely pickled. Does this condiment have a name?

I'm going to ask next time I go. The condiment is pictured in bottom left of the bowl below. It just looks like red peppers.

[image]

Comment: I think that you will get some guesses soon, but I wanted to point out that there are hundreds of different pepper cultivars, which cannot be distinguished by looks, or by broad terms like "medium spicy" - and restaurants, with very few high-end exceptions, don't actively care for the exact cultivar. They are probably using whatever their supplier happens to carry.

Comment: @rumtscho upon re-reading my question I'm making some edits. I'm not really looking for the type of pepper, but more the name of the prepared condiment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it looks more answerable now.

Comment: Could those just be pickled peppers?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like just [Nam Som Prik](https://www.messyvegancook.com/thai-pickled-chillies-nam-som-prik-dong-recipe/), pickled peppers in vinegar.  These get made with any of the [various peppers used in Thailand](https://www.foodrepublic.com/2016/08/31/hot-stuff-what-are-the-different-thai-chilis/), and as such can vary from "medium spicy" to "OMG where's the water".

Comment: thanks! I ended up getting some sweet peppers after the red jalapenos were... too much. i'll see if it's easy as adding vinegar. i'm guessing the restaurant i go to adds sugar.

Comment: They might.  Best flavor is if you can get your hands on some palm sugar.